# Finding a textView from XML of a Custom View for a AlertDialog Fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, textview, android-alertdialog

I have a custom class that extends a dialog fragment that I will later be putting in an activity, however no matter what I do I cannot find the Textview associated with the XML used to create the custom AlertDialog.

EDIT: Mike was right, the onCreateDialog(Bundle ...) is not called before I try to access the textViews, thus leading to the null pointer exception, I cannot, however for the life of me figure out how to create the dialog then try and access the fields, I have attempted to place the code that finds the views in the onAttach(...) method of a fragment because it is the earliest in the lifecycle, however the code the always calls the getter (to get the textView instance in the fragments first and not onCreateDialog or onAttach, is there anyway to ENSURE that the fragment's onCreateDialog or onAttach is called before the getters?

This is in the activity that that will host the fragment
win_frag is an already instantiated instance of the custom fragment, appendStreak is the getter to attempt to get the textView instances from the fragment.

```
mainPanel.getThread().onPause();
            win_frag.show(fragmentManager, "winning");          

            // Set the text in the views accordingly by calling a method from
            // the fragment
            Log.d(TAG, "Attempting to append to the fragment textView");
            win_frag.appendStreak(pongApplication.getStreak());
            win_frag.appendBonus(pongApplication.getBonus());
            win_frag.appendTotal(total);





@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
// Get the layout inflater (needed to put in custom XML)
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.win_screen, null, false);
build.setView(inflatedView);
streakView= (TextView)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.streak_box);
bonusView= (TextView)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.bonus_box);
totalView= (TextView)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.total_box);
}
```

win_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
   android:background="@drawable/metal_background">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:height="50dp"

        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="@string/win_title"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:typeface="monospace"

        />   
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:height="50dp"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:text="@string/streak_title"
         android:textSize="20sp"
           android:textColor="#ffffff"
         android:id="@+id/streak_box"
         /> 

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:height="50dp"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:text="@string/bonus_title"
         android:textSize="20sp"
           android:textColor="#ffffff"
         android:id="@+id/bonus_box"
         /> 

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:height="50dp"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:text="@string/total_title"
         android:textSize="20sp"
         android:textColor="#ffffff"
         android:id="@+id/total_box"
         /> 


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: inflatedView.findviewbyid ...

Comment: @user3200451 check this https://github.com/protocol10/Fragments-sample/tree/master/AlertDialog

Comment: @james The link just tells me how to create a AlertDialog Fragment using the builder class, it does not create it from XML, nor does it specifically address my issue (trying to get a reference from the textView)

Comment: Your code looks good. What specific problem are you having?

Comment: @MikeM. I host the fragment in another activity try to access the Instances of the the TextViews (streakView, bonusView etc...) with a getter and an instance of the fragment class, but when I call the getter I get a null Pointer, which leads me to believe textViews are not properly instantiated.

Comment: Is `inflatedView` a class member of the Fragment? If its scope is just inside a method, then that would explain the problem. Also, if it's not inflated before you call the getter, that would happen.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Override    
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()); 
// Get the layout inflater (needed to put in custom XML)
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.win_screen, null);
build.setView(inflatedView);
streakView= (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.streak_box);
bonusView= (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.bonus_box);
totalView= (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.total_box);
return builder.create();
}
```

Comment: Which are the things you are suggesting to resolve his issue?

Comment: Why are you casting to AlertDialog?

Comment: I think sometimes `AlertDialog` not identified its layout when it is inside the `onClick()` then we have to do like this.

Comment: @ved. This is not code in onClick() it is onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState). Plus you cannot cast from AlertDialog to textView, I do not understand what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: I am not casting AlertDialog to TextView. I am referencing AlertDialog to get the TextView in onCreateDialog(Bundle).Are you tried my edited code.

Comment: @ved. Tried the code, what exactly is the "dialog" in the ((AlertDialog)dialog)?

Answer (score 0):

try changing

`inflater.inflate(R.layout.win_screen, null, false);`

to

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.win_screen, null);
```